# Is there a way to view my starred chat messages?

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-search

I can find a list of messages which I have starred, but I would like (for ego-stroking purposes) to find a list of my messages which other people have starred. Is there any way to find such a list?

Comment: It was possible to search in starred messages for about an hour or two once. That was the good ol' day.

Comment: Basically you want data explorer style mining on our chat logs? +1 for that almost-but-not-quite-creepy feeling this gives me.